# SQL - How to update same row multiple times

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to update a row multiple times.

Example:

```
DECLARE @Formula TABLE
(
    Formula NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO @Formula
SELECT '$v1$ + $v2$ + $v3$'

DECLARE @VariableValues TABLE
(
    Variable NVARCHAR(MAX),
    [Value] DECIMAL(16, 3)
)

INSERT INTO @VariableValues
SELECT '$v1$', 12 UNION
SELECT '$v2$', 14 UNION
SELECT '$v3$', 18

UPDATE f
SET Formula = REPLACE(Formula, Variable, [Value])
FROM @Formula f
CROSS JOIN @VariableValues vv

SELECT * FROM @Formula
```

So in the example case, I would want to update the formula 3 times, replacing each variable with its value.

What actually happens is that only the first variable gets replaced.

Is this possible?

Comment: If `SUM` isn't what you need, what *are* you after, as that is *exactly* what is appears you need. The only alternative I could see would be to iterate and us the `+` operator, but that would perform horribly.

Comment: I'll make a new question then

Comment: Don';t make a new question, [edit] this one.

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: This now goes into what I said below Gordon's answer. SQL **isn't** a scripting language. You can't inject the values of parameters into an expression, and expect SQL Server to dervive it. The `REPLACE` above would, eventually, just result in a `varchar` with the value `'12 + 14 +18'` which is **not** a numerical expression. If you have a scenario like this you have a (major) design flaw. The only way you could achieve this would be with Dynamic SQL, and that is not a rabit hole you want to go down unless you have a very good understand of the language.

Comment: I can use a cursor after replacing the values and EXEC the formula, the problem is that it only replaces the first variable and not all of them, and I didn't want to use a cursor for the replace since it's slow

Comment: The problem isn't the `CURSOR` there, it's the design. That is the *real* problem. Fix the design, fix the problem.

Comment: But I have to do this all in sql server, so is there no way of doing that?

Comment: Like I said, SQL isn't a scripting language; don't treat it like one. You *need* to fix your data model here.

Comment: That doesn't help my situation at all, I'm not allowed to change the structure, I have to get this working the way it is

Answer (score 1):

Use aggregation:

```
UPDATE t
    SET Id = t.Id + t2.sum_id
    FROM @TEST t CROSS JOIN
         (SELECT SUM(t2.id) as sum_id
          FROM @TEST t2
         ) t2;
```

`UPDATE` updates a given row only once.  You need to precalculate the result using aggregation.

Comment: I specified that I didn't want to use a SUM, because my scenario isn't with INTs, I have one row with a formula and I want to replace each variable with a value, that's why I specified "without using a sum"

Comment: @SimãoSantos . . . Whatever you want to do, you need to pre-aggregate the data.  For your question, `sum()` is the appropriate aggregation function.

Comment: aggregation doesn's work for my scenario, I need to update the row multiple times, because I replace $variable1$ with value1, $variable2$ with value2, so on and so on, but I need to do it multiple times

Comment: *"I have one row with a formula and I want to replace each variable with a value"* IF you're saying that you have something like a column with the value `N'ColA + ColB + SUM(ColC)'` you have a major design flaw. SQL isn't a scripting language, it can't take a value of a row, see that it's an expression, and derive it. It also means your question doesn't show your real scenario at all, and you dhuold be showing us what the ***real*** problem is.

Comment: I just wanted to simplify the question but I specified that I wanted it without sum because thats not what I actually need

Comment: @SimãoSantos . . . Ask a new question with a clear explanation, sample data and desired results.  This question has been answered.

Comment: I did specify that I wanted to do that without using a SUM